# How to create a multi-line input box (similar to HTML Textarea)?

Tags: itext

I am running the MultiLineField  example from this link:

http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples-itext5/multiline-fields

However, I am not able to see any multi-line input box that allow people to enter text.

How to can I create a multi-line input box (similar to HTML Textarea)?

**UPDATE**

Here is the code I have now. I am not able to enter any value in the PDF form.

```
 public void createPdf_multilines(String filename) throws DocumentException, IOException {
     PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(createForm());
     PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(filename));
     AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
     form.setField("text", "A B C D E F\nG H I J K L M N\nO P Q R S T U\r\nV W X Y Z\n\nAlphabet street");
     stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
     stamper.close();
 }

 public byte[] createForm() throws DocumentException, IOException {
     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     Document document = new Document();
     PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
     document.open();
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 770, 144, 806);
     TextField tf = new TextField(writer, rect, "text");
     tf.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
     tf.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
     tf.setBorderWidth(2);
     writer.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField());
     document.close();
     return baos.toByteArray();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates a text field that will wrap text when it doesn't fit the width of the text area:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 770, 144, 806);
TextField tf = new TextField(writer, rect, "text");
tf.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
tf.setBorderColor(BaseColor.BLUE);
tf.setText("A B C D E F\nG H I J K L M N\nO P Q R S T U\r\nV W X Y Z\n\nAlphabet street");
tf.setBorderWidth(2);
writer.addAnnotation(tf.getTextField());
```

I have added a border width and a border color, so that you clearly see the field on the page. Maybe that's your problem: maybe the field is there, but you just don't see it.

Note that you shouldn't expect people to be able to resize the field as is possible in HTML. In PDF, all fields have fixed coordinates (in this case `36, 770` and `144, 806`). You shouldn't expect PDF forms to behave the same way as HTML forms behave.

Comment: Bruno, thanks for helping me! I tested your code. I am able to see the border, but I am not able to enter text in the boxed area. I updated my post with all the code I  have. Cheers.

Comment: You use `stamper.setFormFlattening(true)` which removes all interactivity. Remove that line and your form will remain a form. Also: you can set the text at the moment you create the field. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about stamper.setFormFlattening(true)! It works like a charm. Thanks, again!

Comment: Really nice solution..exactly I found the thing I am searching for. I use this in my Table cell as        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 770, 144, 806);
  TextField tf = new TextField(writer, rect, "text");
  tf.setOptions(TextField.MULTILINE);
  tf.setBorderWidth(2);
  
        FieldPositioningEvents events = 
             new FieldPositioningEvents(writer, tf.getTextField());
       
  final PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(headTable);
   PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
   cell1.setCellEvent(events);
   cell1.setFixedHeight(100);
   myTable.addCell(cell1);